# How to print ArcGIS tile map using MapFish print

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, mapfish, mapfish-print

I could able to configure a MapFish print in GeoServer and also did some printing map from OSM. I need to print a map which is from ESRI Mapserver. Is there any way to do it?

Working example:

```
layers: [ 

          { 

            baseURL: 'http://tile.openstreetmap.org',     
            singleTile: false,     
            type: 'OSM', 
             maxExtent: 
                [-20037508.3392,-20037508.3392,20037508.3392,20037508.3392],           
            tileSize: [256, 256],     
            extension: 'png',            
            resolutions: [    
             156543.03390625,    
             78271.516953125,    
             39135.7584765625,    
             19567.87923828125,    
             9783.939619140625,    
             4891.9698095703125,    
             2445.9849047851562,    
             1222.9924523925781,     
             611.4962261962891,    
             305.74811309814453,    
             152.87405654907226,    
             76.43702827453613,    
             38.218514137268066,    
             19.109257068634033,    
             9.554628534317017,    
             4.777314267158508,    
             2.388657133579254,
             1.194328566789627,    
             0.5971642833948135,    
             0.29858214169740677,    
             0.14929107084870338    
           ]    
         },         
   ],
```

Not working example:

```
layers: [ 

              { 

                baseURL: 'http://localhost:69/arcgis/rest/services/Pub/BaseMapEng_LightGray_GCS/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}',     
               type:'xyz',                    
                 maxExtent: 
                    [-20037508.3392,-20037508.3392,20037508.3392,20037508.3392],           
                tileSize: [256, 256],     
                extension: 'png',            
                resolutions: [    
                 156543.03390625,    
                 78271.516953125,    
                 39135.7584765625,    
                 19567.87923828125,    
                 9783.939619140625,    
                 4891.9698095703125,    
                 2445.9849047851562,    
                 1222.9924523925781,     
                 611.4962261962891,    
                 305.74811309814453,    
                 152.87405654907226,    
                 76.43702827453613,    
                 38.218514137268066,    
                 19.109257068634033,    
                 9.554628534317017,    
                 4.777314267158508,    
                 2.388657133579254,
                 1.194328566789627,    
                 0.5971642833948135,    
                 0.29858214169740677,    
                 0.14929107084870338    
               ]    
             },         
       ],
```

getting error as

[image]

I'm getting this error :

```
Error while generating PDF:
org.mapfish.print.InvalidJsonValueException: spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value: http://localhost:69/arcgis/rest/services/Pub/BaseMapEng_LightGray_GCS/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x} (Illegal character in path at index 86: http://localhost:69/arcgis/rest/services/Pub/BaseMapEng_LightGray_GCS/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x})
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain the error message as *ASCII text*. This will make the message legible on all devices and searchable by others.

Comment: @Vince i did edited

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ signs from your URL, and add .png to get tiles data. try:

```
"http://localhost:69/arcgis/rest/services/Pub/BaseMapEng_LightGray_GCS/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png"
```